# Запретить индексацию поисковыми системами

Tags: nginx, поисковые-системы

Есть домен, направленный на локальный сервер `OpenServer`, на котором время от времени открываю разные сайты (направляю на разные папки). Как лучше в этом случае запретить его к индексации поисковыми системами?

Comment: Ты хочешь запретить от индексации сайт на Опен Сервере? У тебя свой сервак что-ли из компьютера сделан?

Comment: Или у тебя локальный Опен сервер и ты просто на будущее хочешь заблочить свой сайт, когда на хостинг зальёшь? Или что? Напиши точнее.

Comment: локальный сервер с несколькими сайтами, которые открываю для разных заказчиков в свое время. Некоторые из заказчиков боятся, что когда открою сайт, он проиндексируется поисковиками. Вопрос в том, можно ли запретить индексацию домена или всех сайтов в папке с `OpenServer`, чтобы не создавать для каждого из них свой `robots.txt` с запретом.

Comment: Скорее нет, чем да. Поисковик то обращается непосредственно к сайту. И как мне кажется, умеет запреты читать либо в роботсе, либо в теле страницы. Ни разу ещё не слышал о каких-то других манипуляциях. Хотя время такое, уже ничему не удивлюсь.

Comment: Можно попробовать в родительской категории файл htaccess создать и в нем запрет сделать. Но точно не могу сказать получиться или нет.

Comment: Вот тут почитай, возможно решение всё же есть. https://semantica.in/blog/prakticheskie-resheniya-zakrytie-sajta-ili-ego-chasti-ot-indeksaczii.html#2